# im trying to make a grid of stars with a nested while loop. It does work with a for loop

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, while-loop, printing, nested

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIIvN.png)
I'm trying to make a grid of stars with a nested while loop.

It does work with a for loop:
but I can't figure out how I can solve it with a while loop,
Does anyone have any idea?

Thnx

Comment: I dont see a `for` loop nor a `while` loop. In fact I don't see any code at all. So what do you expect from us? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you show your for loop? You can transform for loop to very similar while loops.

Comment: post some code - how else can we point out what you've done wrong? seems like the issue is a leading space on the first line - probably an easy fix, but who can tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loops can easily be translated into while loops.

```js
// With a traditional for loop
for (let i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    const string = '*'.repeat(i);
    console.log(string);
}

// With a while loop
let i = 5;

while (i > 0) {
    const string = '*'.repeat(i);
    console.log(string);
    i--;
}
```